# Connect two Next.js Static projects for Translation with Nginx

Tags: nginx, next.js

I have two Next.js projects that are meant to be Landing Pages.
One as the main page and the other one is the translated version.
Thus, wird.app will show the Arabic version while wird.app/en will show the english version.

I exported the two projects (next build && next export) to different directories and used this nginx configs to route between them

```
server {
    server_name www.wird.app wird.app;

    location /en {
        alias /var/www/html/wird.app/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/wird.app.ar/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

The main page is working fine while the translated page doesn't load properly.

Next.js config

```
module.exports = {
   async redirects() {
     return [
      {
         source: "/",
         destination: "/en/",
         permanent: true,
      },
     ];
    },
};
```

Checking the network tab it shows that the requests for the translated page goes to the wird.app/_next/....

How to fix that?
BTW: The website is up and running.

Best